# Color settings don't get applied on graph plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

[image: Got it working][image: Graph with node of same color]Even though am using node draw_networkx_nodes with list of nodes and respective color - those settings don't get applied.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_list=lis_bjp_f, node_color='green', alpha=.5)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_list=lis_bjp_n, node_color='red', alpha=.5)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_list=lis_con_f, node_color='blue', alpha=.5)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_list=lis_con_n, node_color='yellow', alpha=.5)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_list = list(name_set) ,node_color ='purple', alpha = .5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
plt.savefig('graph.png')
plt.show(block = False)
```

Comment: If the answer I give is not correct, can you produce an [MCVE]?

Comment: My answer was not correct.  I've removed it.  In general, a [MCVE] helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace node_list with nodelist
```

node_list is not recognised by [nx.draw_networkx_nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html), but since the function accepts any number of keywords, no error is thrown.

Hence, all nodes are drawn, everytime you call the function. Since at the last time you call the function, you ask for purple nodes, all nodes seem purple.

Comment: I must have spent hours on such stupid mistake, and thank you so much. Also it does seem like inconsistency in argument where node_color but not node_list. :/

Comment: I agree. The arguments are indeed named inconsistently. No error message being shown makes it hard to catch.